# Disable all form elements except those in the form currently being used

Tags: jquery

Say I have a page with multiple forms on it. When one form has information input into it, all the elements of the other forms should be disabled.

I have tried selecting all the forms except the current one using `.not()`, then getting each input element using the `:input` selector and applying the `disabled` property to it, but when information is input, all the elements in all the forms get disabled regardless of which form was used.

```
$('form').on("input", ":input", function() {
    $('form').not(this).each(function() {
      $(this).find(':input').prop('disabled', true);
    });
  });
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/cw1998/6bbd7vpu/3/) (Very messy, but just to demonstrate)
When information is entered into any of the elements in the top form, all the elements in the bottom form should be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the case of that delegate is the input field that got the input event.  you will need to get it's closest('form') before you perform your not() logic.

```
$('form').not($(this).closest('form'))
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!! I had assumed `.not(this)` would be seen as "not this form" because of `'form'` just before. 
I was able to simply this further to avoid using `.each()`:
`$('form').not($(this).closest('form')).find(':input').prop('disabled', true);`
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yeah, no need for the each, :)